# Up-to-date Comparison of High-Speed USB Flash Drives

Tags: performance, usb-flash-drive

I am looking for comparison of the performance of USB flash drives.

I have found several older [comparisons](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/data-transfer-run,1037.html), but I am trying to find a more up-to-date comparisons that apply to the larger storage sizes (32-128GB).

I can try looking up the specs of various drives, but vendors have been known to exaggerate, or use numbers that are on accurate in tests that do not reflect actual usage.  I was hoping to find 3rd party site which had perform testing.

Comment: Good reviews are hard to find for a couple reasons: Product lifecycles tend to be short, they're often made with whatever flash is available for cheap, controllers aren't normally optimized for speed, and everyone is interested in SSDs instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a comparison of nearly every USB 3.0 flash drive, they have standardized tests on all the latest models (last updated around a month ago with the new Lacie ruggedKey).

http://www.whoratesit.com/Best-Flash-Drive/Comparison/1

Note: they only tested 16gb drives as per: 
"Larger capacity drives will tend to have higher write speeds. The 32GB versions of all of these drives will have roughly the same read speeds but most will have double the write speed. It is important to make sure only similar capacity drives are compared."

Answer (score 0):

I found one review of [USB 3.0 devices](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/usb-3.0-thumb-drive-flash-drive,2900.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ultimate comparison of hundreds of user-submitted performance specs for USB Flash Drives: http://usbspeed.nirsoft.net/